# Chrome JS Error: Mixed Content: for roboto

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fonts

I keep getting the error below ONLY on Chrome Browser, however there is single call to http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/* within the page nor its included statics files. I do not have any idea why Chrome makes this call nor where it is coming from. Access same url from any other browser works except Chrome.

Please I will appreciate your help on fixing this error

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.domainname.com/' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font
>   'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKOzY.woff2'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the record and anyone that might be facing similar problem. As @Raj mentioned in his answer, Chrome does not let https sites use resources from http sites.

However, I narrowed down issue when I served an empty page with just HTML & Body tag and confirmed the issue still persisted. This tells me there might be something else wrong somewhere.

And it happened to be one of the installed **Chrome Extensions** that is injecting this fond resource. **I fixed the issue by disabling all Extensions**. I will figure out which one was doing the harm by re-enabling them one after another

Comment: I had the same experience and tracked it down to a third party extension which the client had installed in one of their browsers.  The extra font load attempts and Unsafe Scripts warning all disappeared as soon as I disabled and removed it.  Beware!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not let https sites use resources from http sites. Changing to **https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKOzY.woff2** will solve the problem

Comment: If you read my message, I mentioned "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKOzY.woff2" DOES NOT Exist any where in the code or its included files.

Comment: @Paullo have you check network tab in chrome developer console. You will see where it has been called/referred

Comment: the Network tab indication is wrong for this case. It is pointing to one of the .js files included. And when I try commenting that out to possibly element the error, it will then point the next js. Now I have removed all JS on the Page and it is now pointing to empty line. 

Also notice this page load while on Safari, and when you check the loaded resource Roboto Font is NOT in the list, this keep me wondering why Chrome is injecting this to my page?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was to deactivate a chrome plugin. In my case, it was VLC Video downloader, which inserted this path to an unsecure resource.